# SQL Data synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, sql, client-server

We have multiple client operating the same software application which has same database structure on their individual PCs. All the clients are offline and at different locations (Not connected by LAN etc.)

Is it possible that, each client pc collects its own data and then server can restore client's back up and get updated with each of the clients data. By updating/restoring the data on server should be merged with all the client's data, so that server admin can view activity at each client side.

I hope I am clear.

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Edit: We will be using SQL Server Express 2008 Edition.

Comment: Are your clients and server using MS SQL Server or SQL Server Compact Edition?

Comment: You may try "microsoft sync framework", I think it will help.

Comment: "SQL Server 2008 Edition." doesn't mean anything. There's one or more words missing (there are many editions of SQL Server 2008).

Comment: You might want to consider using Microsoft Sync framework. It is really good framework to sync up your remote(mobile) database with central database server. If PC's are not in the network then you can have some kind of username/password passed on from the client through web-service and have them authenticated at the server side. If they are authenticated then let them proceed for sync up the data. Here is the link [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dennis mentioned you could use [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx).
Synchronization is a non-trivial task because of many factors like conflict handling, change detection, timestamp synchronization.... The Microsoft Sync Framework does that all for you.

There are several other Frameworks that do synchonization. See [OpenSync](http://www.opensync.org/) or [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/).